# serverless-python-requirements throwing an error unable to link babel

Tags: flask, serverless, flask-babel

I recently added flash babel to my serverless flask app and everything works when I run things locally with sls wsgi serve. But when I run a serverless deploy, the packaging step is failing with the below message:

```
Unable to link dependency 'babel' because a file by the same name exists in this service
 Stack Trace --------------------------------------------

Error: Unable to link dependency 'babel' because a file
                             by the same name exists in this service
    at fse.readdirSync.map.e (/tmp/seed/source/node_modules/serverless-python-requirements/index.js:162:19)
    at Array.map (native)
    at ServerlessPythonRequirements.linkRequirements (/tmp/seed/source/node_modules/serverless-python-requirements/index.js:151:40)
From previous event:
    at PluginManager.invoke (/sls-1.40.0/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:408:22)
    at PluginManager.run (/sls-1.40.0/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:439:17)
    at variables.populateService.then (/sls-1.40.0/node_modules/serverless/lib/Serverless.js:109:33)
    at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:617:5)
From previous event:
    at Serverless.run (/sls-1.40.0/node_modules/serverless/lib/Serverless.js:96:6)
    at serverless.init.then (/sls-1.40.0/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless:43:28)
    at /sls-1.40.0/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:111:16
    at /sls-1.40.0/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:45:10
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
From previous event:
    at initializeErrorReporter.then (/sls-1.40.0/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless:43:6)
    at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:617:5)
From previous event:
    at __dirname (/sls-1.40.0/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless:28:46)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/sls-1.40.0/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless:67:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:611:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:160:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:507:3

  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com

  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     OS:                     linux
     Node Version:           6.17.0
     Serverless Version:     1.40.0
```

My requirements file looks like this:

```
click==6.7
Flask==0.12.3
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10.1
MarkupSafe==1.0
Werkzeug==0.12.2
pytest==3.7.2
requests
Flask-Login
pysaml2
flask_babel
```

Any help will be appreciated.. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Some source code reading of serverless python requirements  Turns out serverless python requirements downloads all dependencies to a .requirements folder and then symlinks from there to your project root folder. I already have a few folders that have the same names as the dependencies I use.

babel was one such folder in which I had my babel.cfg file. Once I rename that folder the error goes away.